# Generating a new conf files on Kubeadm 1.13.12

Tags: kubernetes, configuration-files, kubeadm

I just updated an old kubernetes cluster from version 1.12 to 1.13, and i'm trying to generate new config files for it so i can continue to use the cluster after the old expiration date.

It doesn't appear that i am able to generate new config files in this version of kubeadm though, which seems odd.  So hoping im missing some painfully obvious solution here.

I know in other versions of kubeadm(both older and newer), you can run commands similar to

```
sudo kubeadm alpha phase kubeconfig all
```

or

```
kubeadm alpha certs renew admin.conf
```

to generate new confs, but from what i can tell, kubeadm in 1.13 does not have options for the conf files, only the certs.  So I was hoping someone might know of a way to generate new versions of the following files for a v1.13 kubernetes cluster using kubeadm,,,

- admin.conf
- kubelet.conf
- controller-manager.conf
- scheduler.conf

Comment: kubeadm upgrade apply?

Comment: I already did the upgrade to version 1.13.  Was hoping there was a way to use an option in to regenerate the k8s conf files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  Was missing something painfully obvious as i expected.  The command to gen the configs was in the init branch of commands unlike in the alpha branch of commands where i was used to them being.

```
kubeadm init phase kubeconfig all
```